# Изменение меню WP тема Avada

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-plugin

Подскажите, как можно решить данную проблему? Есть сайт на теме WP "Avada", у него есть 6 видов меню в самой теме, но мне ни одна из них не подходит. Как можно заменить меню темы? Плагинами не меняет, возможно, подскажете, какой файл нужно изменить? header.php пересмотрел, может я чего-то не понимаю... Google "горит" уже, но нужного что-то не могу найти... Благодарен любым советам!

Comment: Вопрос неконкретный. Что именно вы хотите изменить? Цвет, шрифты? Расположение элементов? Тема платная, как ее настройки поменять, вам никто не подскажет. Максимум то, что можно увидеть снаружи.  В общем, Создайте минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: мне нужно как-то полностью изменить меню, а кода как такового нет, просто файлы php те которые в самой теме, настройками темы не меняется, пробовал, вот думал может кто подскажет как заменить с помощью кода в самой теме

Comment: [Navwalker](https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker)  можете сделать собственное меню.